# After loading form, Check the items in the list and count down

Tags: powershell

The following code can run successfully, but I can't implement two functions.

1. I hope that when the form is loaded,
   In tabpage1, the list item, item1 and item3 are selected.
   In tabpage2, list item, item4 is selected
2. Add countdown automatic confirmation function,
   If there is no operation within 10 seconds after the form is opened, the OK button will be automatically clicked.
   If there is some operation, cancel the countdown

Please see the picture

[image: pic]

```
#----------------------------------------------
#region Application Functions
#----------------------------------------------

#endregion Application Functions

#----------------------------------------------
# Generated Form Function
#----------------------------------------------
function Show-form_psf {

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Import the Assemblies
    #----------------------------------------------
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $tabcontrol1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl'
    $tabpage1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
    $checkedlistbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox'
    $tabpage2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage'
    $checkedlistbox2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox'
    $buttonOK = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------

    $form1_Load={
        #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

    }

    #region Control Helper Functions
    function Update-ListBox
    {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            This functions helps you load items into a ListBox or CheckedListBox.

        .DESCRIPTION
            Use this function to dynamically load items into the ListBox control.

        .PARAMETER ListBox
            The ListBox control you want to add items to.

        .PARAMETER Items
            The object or objects you wish to load into the ListBox's Items collection.

        .PARAMETER DisplayMember
            Indicates the property to display for the items in this control.

        .PARAMETER Append
            Adds the item(s) to the ListBox without clearing the Items collection.

        .EXAMPLE
            Update-ListBox $ListBox1 "Red", "White", "Blue"

        .EXAMPLE
            Update-ListBox $listBox1 "Red" -Append
            Update-ListBox $listBox1 "White" -Append
            Update-ListBox $listBox1 "Blue" -Append

        .EXAMPLE
            Update-ListBox $listBox1 (Get-Process) "ProcessName"

        .NOTES
            Additional information about the function.
    #>

        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]
            $ListBox,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            $Items,
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
            [string]
            $DisplayMember,
            [switch]
            $Append
        )

        if (-not $Append)
        {
            $listBox.Items.Clear()
        }

        if ($Items -is [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection])
        {
            $listBox.Items.AddRange($Items)
        }
        elseif ($Items -is [Array])
        {
            $listBox.BeginUpdate()
            foreach ($obj in $Items)
            {
                $listBox.Items.Add($obj)
            }
            $listBox.EndUpdate()
        }
        else
        {
            $listBox.Items.Add($Items)
        }

        $listBox.DisplayMember = $DisplayMember
    }
    #endregion

    $buttonOK_Click={
        #TODO: Place custom script here
        $checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems | Out-Host
        $checkedlistbox2.CheckedItems | Out-Host
    }


    # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonOK.remove_Click($buttonOK_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch { Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #> }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    $tabcontrol1.SuspendLayout()
    $tabpage1.SuspendLayout()
    $tabpage2.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($tabcontrol1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
    $form1.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
    $form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
    $form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
    $form1.ClientSize = '284, 262'
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $False
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $False
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form1.Text = 'Form'
    $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
    #
    # tabcontrol1
    #
    $tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage1)
    $tabcontrol1.Controls.Add($tabpage2)
    $tabcontrol1.Location = '22, 17'
    $tabcontrol1.Name = 'tabcontrol1'
    $tabcontrol1.SelectedIndex = 0
    $tabcontrol1.Size = '240, 204'
    $tabcontrol1.TabIndex = 1
    #
    # tabpage1
    #
    $tabpage1.Controls.Add($checkedlistbox1)
    $tabpage1.Location = '4, 22'
    $tabpage1.Name = 'tabpage1'
    $tabpage1.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
    $tabpage1.Size = '232, 178'
    $tabpage1.TabIndex = 0
    $tabpage1.Text = 'tabpage1'
    $tabpage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # checkedlistbox1
    #
    $checkedlistbox1.CheckOnClick = $True
    $checkedlistbox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
    [void]$checkedlistbox1.Items.Add('item 1')
    [void]$checkedlistbox1.Items.Add('item 2')
    [void]$checkedlistbox1.Items.Add('item 3')
    $checkedlistbox1.Location = '26, 27'
    $checkedlistbox1.Name = 'checkedlistbox1'
    $checkedlistbox1.Size = '181, 124'
    $checkedlistbox1.TabIndex = 0
    $checkedlistbox1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # tabpage2
    #
    $tabpage2.Controls.Add($checkedlistbox2)
    $tabpage2.Location = '4, 22'
    $tabpage2.Name = 'tabpage2'
    $tabpage2.Padding = '3, 3, 3, 3'
    $tabpage2.Size = '232, 178'
    $tabpage2.TabIndex = 1
    $tabpage2.Text = 'tabpage2'
    $tabpage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # checkedlistbox2
    #
    $checkedlistbox2.CheckOnClick = $True
    $checkedlistbox2.FormattingEnabled = $True
    [void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add('item 4')
    [void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add('item 5')
    [void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add('item 6')
    $checkedlistbox2.Location = '26, 27'
    $checkedlistbox2.Name = 'checkedlistbox2'
    $checkedlistbox2.Size = '181, 124'
    $checkedlistbox2.TabIndex = 1
    $checkedlistbox2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # buttonOK
    #
    $buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
    $buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
    $buttonOK.Location = '197, 227'
    $buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
    $buttonOK.Size = '75, 23'
    $buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
    $buttonOK.Text = '&OK'
    $buttonOK.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonOK.add_Click($buttonOK_Click)
    $tabpage2.ResumeLayout()
    $tabpage1.ResumeLayout()
    $tabcontrol1.ResumeLayout()
    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
Show-form_psf | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `$form1_Load={}` part, you can cycle through the `tabpage` items and have the desired item's `checked` property to `$true`. You can add a `sleep for 1s` in a `for` loop for 10, counting down and display the value on the form as a label or something. Dont forget to add a `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` interrupt after the sleep command inside the `for` loop.

Now, in each item's `OnCLick` eventhandler you can add a code to set a global flag say `$global:OperationFlag=$true` that can be checked from inside the `do-while` loop like:

```
#lets say you set this somewhere early
$Global:OperationFlag = $false

$i = 10
do
{
    for ($c = 10; $c -gt 0; $c--)
    {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        #This will simulate a 1 second sleep while waiting on interrupts from other operations
    }

    $labelCountdown.Text = $i #Where $labelCountdown is the label that is used on your display to show the countdown.
    #Change this depending on the name you are using.

    $i--
    if ($i -eq 0)
    {
        #hit OK
        $buttonOK.Click()
    }
    if ($Global:OperationFlag -eq $true)
    {
        Return
    }
}
While ($i -gt 0)
```

And return out of the countdown loop when an click event is registered. Or use one of the other events that qualify as an operation in your case like `valuechanged` or something. I cant remember. A `Do-While` loop will also work instead of the `for` loop.

If no event is registered, you can invoke the `OK` button's `click` function when the countdown hits zero.

I know, its not the best way or the only way, but its a start.

Comment: Dont forget to initialize the global flag to `$false` before the loop begins.

Comment: I just learned about powershell Gui programming, I still don't understand, Can you share the code?

Comment: I found some timer code, but I don't know how to use it. 
 https://info.sapien.com/index.php/guis/gui-controls/spotlight-on-the-timer-control